# React Native Input Dismisses Keyboard only first time

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

I found out that due to the usage of Material Top Tabs, if I click on the tab Rather than Swipe, the keyboard will dismiss on the first time when clicking into TextInput.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: could you add some code?

Comment: consider adding a snack that represents your problem